# Check if we have matching data for two columns inside a group

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have some data like:

```
ID   Col1   Col2
---  -----  -----
5    10     10       <--- Matching
5    11     10       
5    15     10
6    22     22       <--- Matching
6    10     22 
6    12     22
```

And I tried a query like:

```
SELECT ID FROM @Table
GROUP BY ID HAVING MAX(COL1) = MAX(COL2)
```

But, this only returns id `6`, as max for group `5` Col1 is `15` which does not match with Col2 max value `10` for group `5`. Is there any way to get all groups 5 & 6 which has matching data `10` & `22` in Col1 & Col2?

Expected Output:

```
ID
---
5
6
```

Just showing the ID of matching group.

Comment: What do you mean when you group by ID column, Did you want to get only one row per ID? what if there tow lines with the same id and equal values in col1 and col2?

Comment: what should be your output?

Comment: Actually original query is a complex one with lots of other columns also and doing other query logics inside group by having clause, so I am trying to get a solution using group by only. I think I found a solution using @uzi concept of case inside max.

Comment: In output only ID is required or also other columns as well?

Answer (score 1):

It is as smiple as this:

```
DECLARE @tblQuestion AS Table
(
    ID int,
    col1 int,
    col2 int
)

INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES
(5,10,10),    
(5,11,10),       
(5,15,10),
(6,22,22),      
(6,10,22), 
(6,12,22);


select distinct ID from @tblQuestion a
where a.col1 = a.col2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query. Maybe it is your requirement, first get same value rows and then get max value from group:

```
DECLARE @tblQuestion AS Table
(
    ID INT,
    Col1 INt,
    Col2 INT
)

INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES(5,10,10)
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES(5,10,21)
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES(5,27,10)
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES(6,10,12)
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES(6,15,15)
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES(6,25,25)
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES(6,18,10)

;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY ID order by Col1 Desc) AS PartNo
    FROM @tblQuestion
    WHERE Col1=Col2

)
SELECT ID,Col1,Col2 FROM T
WHERE PartNo=1
ORDER BY ID, Col1 DESC
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID 
FROM table_name
WHERE (col1 - col2) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct ID FROM table_name
where  COL1 = COL2
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried a different approach, as I needed to use `GROUP BY` & `HAVING` clause due to my original query complexity like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM @Table
GROUP BY ID 
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Col1 = Col2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Just wanted to share my solution here, in case anyone is interested.